# Variable being changed for seemingly no reason in Java

Tags: java

So i just started learning Java yesterday so apologies if this is a bit of a mess.

Basically i am testing the function menuValid() by printing the input from the function questionTime(), my problem is regardless of what my input for the menu is menuValid() will always print '0' as my answer. However the X variable is declared and printed at the same points however x will remain the same and will not be set to '0'.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    
    public static int menu_input;
    public static int x;

    static void menuError() {
        System.out.println("Please pick a valid option.");
        questionTime();
    }

    public static void questionTime() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int menu_input = scan.nextInt();
            x = 25;
            if(menu_input>4 && menu_input < 9){
                menuError();
            }
            if(menu_input>9 || menu_input<1){
                menuError();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(menu_input);
                menuValid();
            }

            scan.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            menuError();
        }
    }

    public static void menuValid() {
        System.out.println(menu_input);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("P4CS Mini Applications");
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("Please Select an option:");
        System.out.println("1) Keep Counting Game");
        System.out.println("2) Number Conversion Tool");
        System.out.println("3) Universal Product Code (UPC) Calculator");
        System.out.println("4) Universal Product Code (UPC) Checker");
        System.out.println("9) Quit");
        System.out.println("Please enter option");

        questionTime();

        }

    }
```

Here is an example of the output of the code so you can see my issue:

```
1) Keep Counting Game
2) Number Conversion Tool
3) Universal Product Code (UPC) Calculator
4) Universal Product Code (UPC) Checker
9) Quit
Please enter option
1
1
0
25
```

Comment: When you name your methods, think in terms of *actions,* not signposts. For example, `questionTime()` should be named something like `getUserInput()`.

Comment: Java naming conventions use cammelCase without underscores for variable and method names. ``menu_input`` should be ``menuInput``.

Answer (score 0):

You re-declared `menu_input` inside `questionTime` (when you did `int menu_input = scan.nextInt();`), which is different from how you treated `x`, where you just changed its value (`x = 25;`). So the `menu_item` you're setting via the `Scanner` is not the `menu_input` class variable you're printing inside `menuValid`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass `menu_input` to `menuValid()` like so -

```
else{
                System.out.println(menu_input);
                menuValid(menu_input); // see this line
            }
```

And change menu valid function as below -

```
public static void menuValid(int menu_input) {
        System.out.println(menu_input);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```